# JavaFX- getting the location of a click on a gridpane

Tags: java, javafx

I have created a JavaFX project that displays an image. I have used a canvas in JavaFX to draw this image and display it on an anchor pane. I have put a gridpane on the top of the image and essentially what I need to do is when the user clicks on a specific box in the grid, find out where that click was made so I can store the coordinates in a text file.

I was thinking of putting a button in each box but this will take a while, is there an easier way of achieving this using just the gridpane? And how can the location/ coordinates of this click gained?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
gridpane.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, e ->{
    e.getX();
    e.getY();
    //And if applicable
    e.getZ();
});
```